# For any tdistinct hree points in $\mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$, there is an unique circle passing through these points.

Tags: complex-analysis

We denote  $\mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$ the complex extended plane. A circle in the complex extended plane passing through $\infty$ is a line.

We have proven that fractional linear transformation maps circles to circles, and that there is an unique fractional transformation $f$ that $z_0, z_1, z_2$ distinct and $w_0, w_1, w_2$ distinct, $f(z_0) = w_0$, $f(z_1) = w_1$, and $f(z_2) = w_2$.

We want to show that a circle in the complex extended plane is uniquely determined by the three points it passes it through. I believe the information I have given should suffice, but I cannot seem to be able to show this.

Existence of circle passing through 3 specified point is easy from fixing any circle and using Fractional linear transformation that sends some 3 point in the fixed points to the desired points. But I am having trouble showing uniqueness.

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So what's a circle from your definition?

Comment: If the 3 points are not collinear, then the bisectors of the 3 arising segments intersect each other in a unique point, that must be the center of the circle.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea circle is something of form |z-a| = b or a line in the complex plane.